# SSRS Report Viewer Control Maximum Pages or Rows

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

When I run a query that brings back many rows (400,000 or so) and try to render it in a Report Viewer Control that is launched with lavascript from my aspx page, with the parameters fed to the report from the page, it will only show the first page in the report and the paging buttons will be greyed out and it will say page 0 out of 0. That is in our dev environment running SSRS 2012 server. In production, we still have SSRS 2008 and what happens there is you just get a blank report with no paging controls. The report works fine with smaller result sets. I'm not sure where the cutoff is yest but 100,000 rows seems to work and 400000 does not.

Now I thought this may have been some issue with the number of rows but maybe it is pages, because I get the same issue with another report that brings back a small number of rows 1000 or so, but the report is one row per page. So the 1000 page report with only 1000 row dataset will have the same issue of only first page in SSRS 2012 and blank in 2008.

These reports works fine on the report manager server no matter how big the results are so this is just isolated to the report viewer asp.net control. Also, this is not just a few reports, I can reproduce this over and over with any report if i make it get enough results.

Does anyone know of any maximum pages or rows for that control? Or anything else that could cause this?

Thanks, hope it is clear what I am asking here.

Also: I think it is IIS 7, but it could be 8. One environment might be windows server 2008 and the other might be 2012, I would need to verify that if needed. The web app is written in asp.net 4.5 with c# code behind. Just trying to name anything else that might be relevant.